# Using php to display welcome message on the same page using conditional statements

Tags: php, html, forms

When the user visits the Visitor Log page, they should be able to see a prompt asking them to enter their name. Upon submitting the form, the same page should display a completely different message welcoming the user to the web page. When the user refreshes the page, the process starts over.
This is what I have tried so far, it works, but I still don't understand how I would display a whole new message after the input.
Here is the code I have I need help with only using PHP to have the correct desired result

#### Attempt

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = "";
$name = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } 
  
  
  else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
    
  }
  
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<p2 id="example-id-name" class="centered-text "></p>
<p><span class="error"></span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
   <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
   
   <span class="error"> <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br> <br>
  
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 
 
</form>

<?php

echo "$name";
echo "<br>";

?>
```

Comment: edited with indentation sorry

Answer (score 0):

Where you're echoing name, you can check whether you have it or not and choose the message to display

```
<?php
if($name) {
  echo "Hi $name!\n Welcome to our store!"
}
else {
  echo "Please enter your name"
}
echo "<br>";
?>
```

Comment: So instead of what I have, <?php

echo "$name";
echo "<br>";

?> I would include that code? When I tried to implement this I was given an error

Answer (score 0):

**You can write inline php and functions**.

Code:

```
<?php
# filter input
function filter($var) {
    return htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($var)));
}
```

```
# validate name
function validate_name(&$name, &$err){
    if(empty($name)){
        $err = "Name is required";
        return;
    }
    $name = filter($name);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
        $err = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
}
```

```
$method = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD');
$err = "";

# If client post a name, then validate the name
if ($method === "POST"){
    $name = $_POST["name"] ?? "";
    validate_name($name, $err);
}
?>
```

```
<!-- The form  -->
<form method="post">
    <label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?=$name ?? ""; ?>">
    </label>

    <!-- Show if error  -->
    <?php if (!empty($err)) { ?>
        <span class="error">
        <?=$err ?>
        </span>
    <?php } ?>

    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php if (isset($name) && empty($err)) { ?>
    <p>Hi <?=$name ?>!</p>
    <p>Welcome to our store!</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: so when I added this code I got an error that the language feature not compatible with PHP versions indicated in my project which one did you use?

Comment: I updated the code for compatibility with older versions.

Comment: PHP 7.1.19 (cli) (built: Aug 17 2018 20:10:18) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

Comment: It depends of what language feature. Can you tell me witch is it ?

Comment: This helped very much is there a way to keep the entry box present even after the submission?

Comment: I get the error for function filter(string $var) and function validate_name(string &$name, string &$err

Comment: Ok, its was the type string before the var.
I used php 7.3.
I removed the "<?php if(!empty($err) || $method === "GET"){ ?>" since you want it visible.

Comment: ok I will try to update php and see if that helps me get to desired result thank you

Comment: ok thank you that worked! I just need to remove please enter your name after the name entry